# Reactive Forms compatible component with its own data source

Tags: angular, dropdown, angular-reactive-forms

I have a component `DropdownBase` which is a dropdown based con *select* and *option* and it implements the **ControlValueAccessor** for being compatible with Reactive Forms.

The component implementation tried to be generic for the input data, it has the next inputs:

- optionList: any[]
- labelKey: string
- valueKey: string

So for creating the options i will iterate over optionList and getting the label and the value with labelKey and valueKey.

Until this point everything is okay (let me know if you have a better idea), but now let's say i have a very specific case for my dropdown, let's call it `CountriesDropdown`. This implementation use a *service* for getting the countries.

Here is where the really question comes, suppose the next component hierarchy:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input .../>
  <dropdown-base ...></dropdown-base>
  <dropdown-base ...></dropdown-base>
  <dropdown-base ...></dropdown-base>
<base-form>
```

For the case where every dropdown has his own service (data source) should the container component have all the service injections? Or if for the example of `CountriesDropdown` should i make a container component with the countries service call and the instantiation of `DropdownBase`? (If so, how can i handle the **formControlName** for the container component)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar, but went with the option of passing a method reference to the component for service calls.

```
<generic-type-ahead
    formControlName="customer"
    placeholder="Customer"
    [httpFn]="getCustomersTypeAhead">
</generic-type-ahead>
```

Then in the parent component, I defined getCustomersTypeAhead:

```
getCustomersTypeAhead = (s: string) => this.customerClient.getCustomerPickList(s);
```

In the child component, I defined HttpFn as an Input():

```
  @Input() httpFn: (s: string) => Observable<any[]>;
```

So far this has been workable.